Excel return sum of variable date in row where criteria is met
I need to find a date in a row 3:3, and then add all the amounts in that column where in a different column A:A the text is = to a specific criteria



Criteria
1/1
1/2
1/3




Bob
1
4
2


Sue
3
1
3


Jill
1
1
1


Bob
2
1
1


Sue
2
3
0



I tried sumifs but I get a #value error because the criterias aren't the same size.
What I want:
To know the sum for Bob on some variable date. For example if I put in 1/2, the answer should come out to 5. But if I change the date option to 1/1 the sum for Bob should be 3.

It can be the simple solution:

[F6]=SUM(B2:D6*(A2:A6=F2)*(B1:D1=F4))


This is perfect and glaringly obvious now, sometimes the simple solution is the hardest to get to, thank you.

How is it going?
